# How to sign in after hashing pw with salt? <==EDITED VERSION #2 ==>

Tags: php, passwords, hash, sha1

This is my 2nd edit on this. I've been banging my head against the wall for few days now and feel like I am very close. I've tried many different versions of this third code chunk and just can't get it. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ( Its the third code chunk that is changed )

```
if(!$error) {
    $alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    $rand = str_shuffle($alpha);
    $salt = substr($rand,0,40);
    $hashed_password = sha1($salt . $_POST['Password']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `Users` (
                `FirstName`,
                `LastName`,
                `Email`,
                `Password`,
                `salt`,
                `RelationshipToCF`,
                `State`,
                `Gender`,
                `Birthday`,
                `Status`
        )VALUES(
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstName']) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastName']) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "',
                '" . $hashed_password . "',
                '" . $salt . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['RelationToCF']) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['State']) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sex']) . "',
                '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DateOfBirth_Year'] . "-" . $_POST['DateOfBirth_Month'] . "-" . $_POST['DateOfBirth_Day']) . "',
                'pending'
    )";
    mysql_query($query, $connection);
```

Here is the method I am using to update existing passwords:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Users`";
$request = mysql_query($query,$connection);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($request)) {
    $alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    $rand = str_shuffle($alpha);
    $salt = substr($rand,0,40);
    $hashed_password = sha1($salt . $result['Password']);
    $user = $result['id'];

    $query2 = "UPDATE `Users` SET `salt` = '$salt' WHERE `id` = '$user'";
    $request2 = mysql_query($query2,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $query3 = "UPDATE `Users` SET `encrypted_passwords` = '$hashed_password' WHERE `id` = '$user'";
    $request3 = mysql_query($query3,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

So now I want to allow the user to sign in with the password they signed up with and at this point they can only sign in with the hashed password. Obviously this has not been applied to the real database quite yet.

Here is the query on the sign in pages that I am going to need to alter:

```
    if(isset($_POST['subSignIn']) &&
       !empty($_POST['email']) &&
       !empty($_POST['password'])) {

        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $query = "SELECT
             `id`,`email`,`password` FROM `Users`
             WHERE `Email` = '" . $email . "' AND
             `Password` = '" . $password . "'  &&
             `Status` = 'active' LIMIT 1";
        $request = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

        if(@mysql_num_rows($request)) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($request);
            $_SESSION['LIFE']['AUTH'] = true;       
            $_SESSION['LIFE']['ID'] = $result['id'];

$query = "UPDATE `Users` SET` LastActivity` = '" . date("Y-m-d") ." " . date("g:i:s") . "'   WHERE `id` ='" .mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['LIFE']['ID']) . "' LIMIT 1";

            mysql_query($query,$connection);

            if(!empty($_POST['return'])) {          
                header("Location: " . $_POST['return']);        
            }else{
                header("Location: Dashboard.php?id=" . $_SESSION['LIFE']['ID']);
            }
        }else{
            $_SESSION['LIFE']['AUTH'] = false;      
            $_SESSION['LIFE']['ID'] = false;    
        }
```

I have been scouring the webernet for methods but figured I would take advantage of all the great minds on here and fish for a suggestion/method/tutorial/point in the right direction

<==My attempt after the original 5 answers==>

```
 i

f(isset($_POST['subSignIn']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {


    $query = "SELECT id FROM cysticUsers WHERE Email = '$email' AND Password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt,'$password')) AND Status = 'active' LIMIT 1";
    $request = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());

if(@mysql_num_rows($request)) {

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($request);
        if (sha1($row['salt'] . $_POST['password']) === $row['password']) {


        $_SESSION['CLIFE']['AUTH'] = true;
        $_SESSION['CLIFE']['ID'] = $result['id'];

        // UPDATE LAST ACTIVITY FOR USER
        $query = "UPDATE `cysticUsers` SET `LastActivity` = '" . date("Y-m-d") . " " . date("g:i:s") . "' WHERE `id` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['CLIFE']['ID']) . "' LIMIT 1";
        mysql_query($query,$connection);

        if(!empty($_POST['return'])) {
            header("Location: " . $_POST['return']);

        }else{
            header("Location: CysticLife-Dashboard.php?id=" . $_SESSION['CLIFE']['ID']);
            }
        }

    }else{

        $_SESSION['CLIFE']['AUTH'] = false;
        $_SESSION['CLIFE']['ID'] = false;

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You mean how to validate the entered password, right?

Comment: You should really properly indent your code so that it's somewhat readable and consistent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you are not actually using the users password when they make an account.

In the first block of code:

```
$hashed_password = sha1($salt . $result['Password']);
```

should be something like:

```
$hashed_password = sha1($salt . $_POST['Password']);
```

I think you are storing the hashed salt only, basically enabling a login with any empty password!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have time to go through the whole blocks of code, but basic salt / hash validation is as follows:

```
$user         // User has a $password and a $salt. $password = hash($plaintext . $salt);
$password     // Password we are checking.
return $user->password == hash($password . $user->salt);
```

Comment: @Mark: Yes, I knew that. Been working with non-PHP stuff recently. I almost forgot the `$`'s too.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to validate the entered password, you would do the same as with the original password: prepend the salt and hash that value.

So lookup the salt that was used when hashing the original password and use it when hashing the entered password and then compare the stored hash with the new calculated hash. So basically:

```
$query = "SELECT `salt`, `password` FROM `Users` WHERE `Email` = '" . $email . "'";
$request = mysql_query($query,$connection) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($request)) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($request);
    if (sha1($row['salt'] . $_POST['Password']) === $row['password']) {
        // user authentic
    } else {
        // user not authentic
    }
}
```

If they are the same, the entered password is probably<sup>1</sup> the same as the original entered.

---

<sup>1) It’s only probably the same and not exactly the same because there is always the probability for a [collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack) where two input values have the same hash value.</sup>

Comment: I think you should elaborate on "probably" slightly :)

Comment: @JoshK there is still a probability of that happening even with unique hash and salt for each user?

Comment: @Lightening: The probability is very low. MD5 collision have been demonstrated with byte arrays, not actual conditions.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Can you make your third codeblock more readable?</s>

---

Here's how I'd go about it -

- Encrypt it when they register, store the password + salt.
- When they log in, get the salt that is associated with the username they're trying to log in on.
- Hash the password they entered (when logging in) with the salt from the database.
- Compare the login password with the password in the database.

Should be easy.

For example:

```
$hashed_password = sha1($salt . $result['Password']);
```

Store both `$hashed_password` and `$salt` in your database.

When they sign in, the password you'd compare the `$hashed_password` above to would be something like:

```
$password = sha1($row['salt'] . $_POST['password']);
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You would first need to grab the salt key from the database by searching on the entered username, and then you would hash the entered password with the salt you grabbed from the database and check that it matches the password for the username in the database.  It would look something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT salt FROM Users WHERE username='$user'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("AAAAGH!  *Thud*");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$salty_password = sha1($row['salt'], $_POST['password']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$salty_password'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("AAAAGH!  *Thud*");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo "Successfully authenticated!";
}
else {
    echo "Failed to Authenticate.";
}
```